# Highcharts Crop datalabels inside pie

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I found example, how to set datalabels inside pie series:

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                distance: -30
            }
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-distance/

But How I can crop datalabel, which doesn't fit in slice?
Thanks!

Comment: There's not direct connection between pie slice and label, but you can use `dataLabels.formatter`, to decide what should be returned (if anything). See simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cvwoosqv/